# why event.target.value is empty on keyup

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Hi I have a chat where I use `textarea` and `onKeyUp` I send messages , but the problem is when I fast typing `1, press enter, 2, press enter, 3 press enter, 4 press enter`. I have missed `3` in my list of messages. After checking logs I see that `event.target.value is ""` sometimes if I type fast.

```
onKeyUp($event): void {
    const message = this.textarea.value;
    console.warn('onkeup event ', $event)
    console.warn('onkeyup event target value ', $event.target.value)
    console.warn('onkeyup value', message)...
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give some of your code in `codesandbox` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event) is a keyboard event, which doesn't always correlate to your elements' value changing.

You should use the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event for monitoring changes in value and the [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event) for keybindings.

Comment: even though if I see this character in event.key ?

Comment: Yes, cause its the key from the event. The event doesn't imply the elements' value has changed.